# Loopback AngularJS SDK - query related models

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

The loopback documentation states that the AngularJS "SDK creates a Category.products() method that can be used to list all products in a given category."

```
$scope.products = Category.products({
    id: $scope.category.id,
});
```

This works fine but, how do I return a list of all categories with all related products.  I have been through the documentation and the source core (lb-services.js) and can't see how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at this, maybe helpful: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html

Comment: This link relates to the Node API, not the the AngularJS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out.
You need to create a remote method in the parent model (ensure you've set up the relationships between the models).

```
Supplier.supplierServices = function (cb) {
    var response;
    Supplier.find({include: 'Services'}, function (err, suppliers) {
        console.log('err', err, 'suppliers', suppliers);
        response = suppliers;
        cb(null, response);
    });
};
```

Then run lb-ng to expose the api to the angular SDK.  You can then call the remote method from the client.